# Is there anyway to show some message while recording video in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, imagepicker

Hi Some numeric text i want to show while user open the camera for recording. I am using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package for record video. As of now i handled by showing [flutter toast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast) but that will be disappear in 5 sec. if anyone have idea to resolve this issue please share it here.

Comment: you can create platform specific code for increasing android toast duration . use this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/988256/How-to-Show-a-Toast-for-a-Specific-Duration-in-And.  For ios and web have duration propery available in flutter_toast package

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I used [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package instead of using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker), by using camera package we can set the size and overlapped designs.